# sound only playing through headphones on certain devices with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, iphone-4, ipad-2

I have a weird problem for you all.

*MPMoviePlayerController* is playing the video fine, and the audio ONLY plays through headphones.

The real drag is that this only happens on *some* iPads and iPhones, even the SAME EXACT MODELS
running the SAME EXACT SYSTEM!

I've created a simple failing example here:

http://www.porcaro.org/MPMoviePlayerController/TestMovie.zip

I've seen it run fine and fail on iPhone 4S, iPhone 4 and iPad 2.

Here is the most relevant code.  Thanks for any insight, I'm going to submit a bug to Apple as well:

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    moviePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/intro.m4v", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    theMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    movieView = [self view];
    movieRect = [[self view] frame];
    controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

    theMoviePlayer.controlStyle = controlStyle;
    theMoviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if (1) {
        NSLog(@"Created theMoviePlayer: %@.  Playing: %@", theMoviePlayer, moviePath);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(checkForEndOfMovie:)
                                          name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                          object:theMoviePlayer];

    // this line doesn't fix the problem                                                                                                       
    //[theMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];                                                                                                          
    [[theMoviePlayer view] setFrame:movieRect];
    [movieView addSubview: [theMoviePlayer view]];
    [theMoviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but maybe it'll help someone. I came across the same issue and found out it was happening when the phone is in silent mode only.

Solution is to set the player's useApplicationAudioSession property to false.

```
[theMoviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was happen to me once playing video on iPad 2 using mpMoviePlayer. The video was playing perfectly but audio only comes when earphones connected.

Solution to solve the problem:

```
[theMoviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
```